# Question about buffering, getchar() and scanf()?

Tags: c, buffer

I am learning C and have some issues. Please, take a look at the picture below:

[image]

When reading the highlight text, I am quite confused. Is it that: when the user starts entering some inputs, the input is put directly and immediately in the buffer. And when Enter key is hit ('\n'), the program reads and gets input from the buffer and then clear the buffer?

If it is, suppose in the program, I use: `scanf("%d", &a_variable)` and then I enter **123astring**, then **123** is read and clear from the buffer.So, In the buffer now contains "**astring**"?

Am I right? Or I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the return key. :)

Comment: You're mixing up a generic text about buffering with a specific instance, scanf, that may not even be using a read buffer. Your question isn't answerable because it depends on implementation details of scanf and the stdio package of which it is a part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really are two buffers.
The first is the one they are talking about.  It allows the user to type in stuff, then delete, etc. without the program ever seeing any of it.
The second buffer is what would be holding the remaining "astring".

A good way to think of it is the first buffer passes to the second buffer when Enter is pressed.  The second buffer is read by scanf.  And if it is empty, the program waits.

The second buffer is pretty much always there.  If it wasn't, you would have to be running scanf exactly when the user typed which is not true even in the 'unbuffered' case.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that since there is this sort-of two-buffer system, if you call scanf("%d", &some_int);scanf("%c", &some_char); and your input is "123h", the user will only be prompted to input ONCE since the buffer was never fully cleared

Comment: @Greg: Well, the user isn't ever really 'prompted' from this code at all.  A better way to think about it is the program only blocks waiting for input ONCE because when the second scanf hits, the data is already there.

Comment: If stdin is unbuffered, then there is no  second buffer (or rather, it is only one byte long to support ungetc). scanf doesn't have to be running exactly when the user typed, because it simply does a read() or equivalent to get data from the underlying layer. And there doesn't even need to be a buffer for the underlying layer ... e.g., if doing raw mode I/O from a terminal.